# Fifo Based Sales in MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, fifo

Please help to to get out of situation

I have Product A with 3 different batch numbers

```
Product   Batch   Qty
  A         1     10
  A         2     10
  A         3     10
```

If I put sell value 25 items then automatically sales report should be seen like this

```
Product   Batch   Sale
  A         1      10
  A         2      10
  A         3      5
```

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

This query will do that:

```sql
SELECT 
    ProductBadge.Product, 
    ProductBadge.Batch, 
    ProductBadge.Qty, 
        (Select Sum(Qty) 
        From ProductBadge As T 
        Where 
            T.Product = ProductBadge.Product And 
            T.Batch <= ProductBadge.Batch) AS Total, 
    IIf([Total]-[Order]<=0, [Qty], [Order]-([Total]-[Qty])) AS Sale
FROM 
    ProductBadge;
```